# Where can I find a complete list of the ranking of the Ubuntu App Showdown's applications?

Tags: application-development

My application participated at the Ubuntu App Showdown contest and I wanted to know its ranking.

Where can I see it?

Also, will there be a ranking for every separate criterion of every separate application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an overall ranking anywhere, but I suspect if it does become available, then it should show up on the [blog feed here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/feed/).  This is also where they plan to do community voting according to a link from an Ubuntu tweet.

Comment: Shouldn't the developers be informed for the process? Why is everything being done "behind the scenes" ?

Comment: Once the top is decided, I think the other rankings may be not disclosed to save complexity and feelings issues.  The community voting part you mean?  I think if you're interested you follow the app-dev mailing list and the Ubuntu tweets.